# Cypher: Update relations between all pairs of particular list of nodes

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, combinations

I'm working with **Neo4j** and I have some concerns about how I could do some queries in **Cypher** to **keep the performance high**.

I have graph with nodes that has the label "Thing". And each of these nodes has property '**pk**' (Integer)

So, given a list of pks like **[123, 34, 125]** I would like to **create/update** (if exists) a relation between nodes of all pairs that we can get of the combination of them.

**(123, 34), (123, 125), (32, 125)** and for each r of between the nodes of the pairs set **r.weight = 0** (if the relation is created) or do **r.weight += 1** (if already exists)

Currently I do the combinations in Python using itertools.combination(pks, 2) and then I do for each pair c1, c2:

```
'MATCH (c1:Thing {pk: %(c1_pk)s}), (c2:Thing {pk: %(c2_pk)s}) ' \
'CREATE UNIQUE c1-[r:KNOWS]-c2 ' \
'SET r.weight=coalesce(r.weight, 0)+1 RETURN c1, r.weight, c2' % {'c1_pk': c1_pk,
                                                                  'c2_pk': c2_pk}
```

But I don't like to call that query for each pair, because the performance sucks when the list of pks is long since the combinations and queries will be length(pks)*(length(pks)-1)

How could I do that?

**EDIT:**
There are around 15000 "Thing" nodes and always will be the same quantity.
and there is a constraint to be unique the pk attribute (t:Thing t.pk is unique)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any constraints on where you're creating these pairwise relationships, so you're trying to do this as a cartesian product.  It's going to be slow if you have a lot of nodes.

But one mistake I can see in the query is that you're trying to create each relationship twice; let's say you wanted to create a relationship from X -> Y.   You're doing that once for X -> Y, and then again for Y -> X.

You can cut that in half by only doing each one once, like this:

```
MATCH (c1:Thing {pk: %(c1_pk)s}), (c2:Thing {pk: %(c2_pk)s}) 
CREATE UNIQUE c1-[r:KNOWS]-c2 
SET r.weight=coalesce(r.weight, 0)+1 RETURN c1, r.weight, c2' % {'c1_pk': c1_pk,
                                                                  'c2_pk': c2_pk}
WHERE c1.id < c2.id
```

Note that we're ordering the nodes by ID.  Since they all have different IDs, you'll do X -> Y, but not Y -> X.

This makes your overall process go from length(pks)*length(pks)-1 to:   ( length(pks)*length(pks)-1 ) / 2.

But, there's no way to get around that what you're trying to do is O(n^2)

Comment: Thanks buddy! The WHERE statement could save some time :)
And what about the cartesian product, is it possible to make it with Cypher and not computing outside of the query?

Comment: Your query does the cartesian product in cypher, not outside.  For what it's worth, when you do that, the query is going to be slow.  Doesn't matter if you do it in java or in cypher.  You're trying to create new edges from everything to everything else; no matter what further optimizations, it'll always be O(n^2)

Comment: +1 Thanks buddy,

So I need to change also the query to this:
 
MATCH (c1:Thing), (c2:Thing) 
CREATE UNIQUE c1-[r:KNOWS]-c2 
WHERE c1.id < c2.id AND c1.pk in %(list_pks)s AND c2.pk IN %(list_pks)s
SET r.weight=coalesce(r.weight, 0)+1 RETURN c1, r.weight, c2'